# Rolling with slipping, direction of the vector of kinetic friction

Tags: friction

I have a question about the direction of kinetic friction in the following situations:

(1) A wheel is being accelerated ($\Delta \omega>0$) in the air, then it is let on the ground and starts rolling with slipping.

(2) A car is being accelerated ($\Delta v>0$) so that its wheels start slipping.

In both situations: will the vector of kinetic friction be pointed in the same direction as the wheel goes or in the opposite?

Am I right to think that: in the first situation it will point in the same direction as the velocity vector because initially $\omega R>v$ so for the slipping to stop we need to have $\omega R=v$, so it must be $\Delta v>0$, so $a>0$ and then from the conservation of energy we get that $\Delta \omega <0$. In the second situation it is the opposite: we the slipping starts, we have $v>\omega R$, so the kinetic friction vector will point in the opposite direction from the velocity vector, and $v$ will decrease, while $\omega$ will increase and eventually $v=\omega R$.

Thanks in advance for any informative answers.

Comment: Why v>ωR. I should think the opposite since pressing the speeder increases the rpm but barely the car speed. In both cases friction counteracts the wheel spin and is directed along the velocity vector.

Comment: But what if the accelerating force exceeds the maximum static friction force? Do we have $\omega R>v$ then?